# How to redirect http requests to another directory by htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Whats up guys.

I have a problem that I want to create group of similar php pages under one directory and client request it.

like that:

```
countries/egypt.php
countries/algeria.php
countries/oman.php

and so on.
```

if client requests https://example.com/egypt apache server calls /var/www/html/countries/egypt.php

and when client enter https://example.com/oman apache server calls /var/www/html/countries/oman.php

and so on.

my question here how to it with htaccess and apache server ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this .htaccess in your site root:

```
RewriteEngine On

ewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/countries/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ countries/$1.php [L]
```